# SqlDataSource Error when trying to run stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

when trying to test sqlDataSource running Stored Procedure i get an Error:
"there was an Error executing the query. please check the syntax of the command and if present, the types and values of the parameters and ensure they are correct.
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain value violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints"

the stored procedure is:

```
USE [FAB28]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spPLCIOFilter]    Script Date: 11/30/2011 15:39:33 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spPLCIOFilter]
(
    @filter1 VARCHAR(50) = '%',
    @filter2 VARCHAR(50) = '%',
    @slot VARCHAR(50) = '%' 
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
       [PLC] "PLC RIO"
      ,[SIGNAL] SIGNAL
      ,[RACK] RACK
      ,[SLOT] SLOT
      ,[POINT] POINT
      ,[CARD] CRAD
      ,[TAG] TAG
      ,[PROJ] PROJ
      ,[DESCRIPTION] "DESCRIPTION"
      ,[ADDRESS] "ADDRESS"

    FROM [FAB28].[dbo].[PLC_TAGS2]
    where [PLC] <> ''
    and [PLC] LIKE '%' + @filter1 + '%'
    and [PLC] LIKE '%' + @filter2 + '%'
    and [SLOT] LIKE '%' + @slot + '%'
    ORDER BY [PLC RIO],[RACK],[SLOT],[POINT]

END
```

the weird thing is that i succeed running the query inside the SP when i put values instead of variables.

can someone help me ?

here's the sqlDataSource code that using the SP:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_PLC_IO" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FAB28ConnectionString_PlcIO %>" 
                        SelectCommand="spPLCIOFilter" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddl_filter1" DefaultValue="" Name="filter1" 
                                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddl_filter2" DefaultValue="" Name="filter2" 
                                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddl_filter_slot" DefaultValue="" Name="slot" 
                                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Please post the code where you are calling the sproc.  My guess is that one of your parameters is too long or the wrong type.

Comment: i try the stored procedure with "%" in all parameters, and also with real parametrs an always i get this error!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ORDER BY clause is not correct:

```
ORDER BY [PLC RIO],[RACK],[SLOT],[POINT]
```

[PLC RIO] is not a column. What happens when you change it to...

```
ORDER BY [PLC],[RACK],[SLOT],[POINT]
```